# Function not working in app.js but in index.html working library reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, newrelic

I'm having a problem when using a function from the New Relic library,

[Can try with codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lucid-wood-kl74z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

If I use this function in public/index.html (command in codesandbox) it works:

screenshot in inspect element working :

[image]

well the problem is if I create my own helpers function and create in app.js it doesn't work

below is the app.js file :

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { newRelicConfig } from "./newRelic";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/jsx";
    script.innerHTML = newRelicConfig(
      "3277692",
      "3277692",
      "NRJS-93eea892ddd7204acfd",
      "1091749869"
    );
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>New Relic</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

in file ./newRelic function newRelicConfig

the function of NRJS does not exist :

[image]

How to work around a function in app.js like with index.html ?

Comment: You might possibily have sensitive data exposed in your code and codesandbox (accountID, trustKey etc.)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a syntax error while trying to execute your function in newRelix.jsx, so first of all double check the function.

That being said, adding a javascript function in a script tag to your HTML document is not the same as executing that function. You could try adding it as a self invoking function. Also note the the type should be `text/javascript` (not `text/jsx`):

```
useEffect(() => {
    let functionBody = newRelicConfig(...); // omitting params here, as they're possibly sensitive
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.innerHTML = `(function(){${functionBody}})();`;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in function newRelicConfig screenshoot error https://i.imgur.com/Ic0GyNB.png, this function newRelicConfig https://pastebin.com/ae933h3e @Ibsn